# How to create a database schema for storing filter criteria in MySQL?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, database, entity-framework-6

I am creating a simple app where an admin can filter the users on the basis of several criteria like a,b,c,d,etc..

I am looking to implement a functionality where an admin can save the created search filter for later use. Search filters can be of several types and can have different values. Also, all the search filters have some common attributes.

Can somebody give me an idea of the database schema for storing such search filters in the database. Should I store the mysql clauses in database like "WHERE a < 1000", "WHERE b=1"...? Or should I store the entire query which gets generated?

Kindly suggest me a suitable database schema to store such filters so that they can be retrieved for later use.